# What is a good word for the permission of a complementary state of affairs?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

Suppose that it is permitted to do not-p. What would be a good word for characterising p? Would it be reasonable to say that p is "contramitted"? Could we, alternatively, perhaps say that p is "antimitted"?

Comment: Are you limiting "p"  somehow? Do you want a word to characterize p both if p = eating and p = murder?

Comment: I do not presuppose any limit.

Comment: So if you assume that it in the context is permitted to not eat and that it in the context also is permitted to not murder, then the word I seek would in the context characterize both eating and murder.

Comment: If not-p is allowed, p may be either allowed or forbidden. For example, assuming that you must not underestimate a quotation, you cannot draw any conclusion on the possibility of overestimating it.

Comment: There are such logical matters concerning these, yes.

Comment: *contingent*; *variable*? I must admit this (programming?) question is beyond my pay grade. Can you define *contramitted* and *antimitted*? And WTH is 'p' ? ;p  - Also, a *state of affairs* (a condition) does not require permission, though it might have a (pre)requisite or be contingent upon other factors or criteria. - Eating and murder both fit the scripted (written in advance) criteria of being `p`?

Comment: **If** you *are not doing [whatever]*, **then** it is permitted.   You are effectively looking for a term that allows you to precisely deny the antecedent:  **If** you *are doing [whatever]*, **then** it is ___.   No such logical conclusion follows.

Comment: Let's define p as "what I say" and not-p as "the contrary of what I say": If you can do *the contrary of what I say*, then doing *what I say* is just a **possibility**.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific word for this. You would just say "Not eating is permitted".

Comment: Or "You don't have to eat"

Comment: I know that there is no word for this and that is why I use the tag "neologisms".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are permitted to do both `not-p` and `p`, then `p` is *optional*.

If either `p` or `not-p` could be passively default choices, like not eating, then you could say that `p` could be *opt-in* or *opt-out*, depending on context.

But to try to say, "`not-p` is permitted" in `p` form ("`p` is ___ implies that `not-p` is permitted.") doesn't seem possible. Again, *optional* seems to be the only word that fits the blank.

Comment: Optional does obviously not answer my query. To this confer my comment above where I clarify that murder and eating both fit the category I want to isolate, but murder is of course not morally optional. Your suggested answer is not helpful, and it should be deleted.